# Update case status after case auto response

Tags: workflow, status, case-auto-response

I created a workflow and set rule to change Case Status to Awaiting Customer respons. There is also a auto response which will be sent after case creation.

Now the case status is not changing to Awaiting Customer Response based on workflow rule, but is being changed to In-Progress, may be due to auto-response sent.

How to make status to Awaiting customer Response after auto-response is sent, and not In-Progress.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the order of execution, Auto-response rules run before Workflow rules, So if your case was satisfying the workflow rule entry criteria, it would have changed the status to Awaiting Customer Response.

Please switch on the debug levels for Workflow rules and check if the case is satisfying the criteria or not.

Also check if there are any triggers which could be changing the status to 'In progress' as the workflow rule field update might be triggering the triggers again.